# Can we call Native API from JavaScript based Office plugins

Tags: javascript, c#, vba, ms-office

> We can develop MS Office add-ins using VBA, .Net and javascript.
>
> From VBA, we can call Native API's (i.e  C, C++ functions).
>
> But, I am not sure, if it is possible to call native API's from
>   javascript too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can!

A quick Google search brought this up:

https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office

Good Luck!

Comment: Hello Vsharper,
Shared link mentions nothing about calling Native APIs from within Office Plugin created via JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

[Office.js add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#anatomy-of-an-office-add-in) designed in mind "write once runs everywhere (where Office supported)". This is why the technology is based on JavaScript. Assume your JS add-in work and available to end users. What would you call "native API" on Windows Desktop, iOS device or OSX? There is no such thing across platform listed, right? Every platform has its own Platform API.

As the conclusion to the point you cannot (should not even try) to call to any platform API functions, instead use what JavaScript and Office.js API offer.